# Using do while loop freezes unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

So i want to make my plank go from point *A* to *B* and than stops when it reaches B. I implemented `do while loop`, `for-loop` but unfortunately unity **freezes** each time i hit play scene button, Any idea why its happening?

```
public class movingplank : MonoBehaviour 
{
    public Rigidbody2D Rigidbody2d;        
    float x;   
    Vector2 ve = new Vector2();

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () 
    {
        Rigidbody2d = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () 
    {  


        do 
        {   ve = Rigidbody2d.transform.position;
             x = ve.x;      // storing x component of my plank into float x 
           Rigidbody2d.velocity = new Vector2(1f, 0f);
        } while (x <-4);   // move plank till it reaches point B
    } 
}
```

Comment: Any apparent reason for down voting my question?

Comment: Wasn't me, but I'd assume the downvote is due to your having a while condition without ever actually changing the values in that condition. A pretty basic error.

Comment: @Immersive i have placed it inside loop, check now does it make sense ?

Comment: Esla, consider Unity's game loop as this: 1. For each script (sequentially), run its `Update()` method. 2. Update physics (apply velocity to each object's position, etc.) 3. Draw the scene. 4. Repeat from 1. Your method prevents Unity from moving on to step 2, so x can never change. You have to understand that `Update()` is called many times a second (for example: 60 fps - it's called 60 times).

Comment: @john thanks that helped me cleared some of my doubts. but how using if else statement in this case solves the problem

Comment: I'm not sure how I can make it clearer really. `Update()` is called every frame by the game loop. The body's position is updated outside of the script. You can't wait for the change in your `Update()` method, you just need to check the conditions that satisfy what you want to do.

Comment: @john ohk got it now loops take alot longer than if statement and that messes up with update method. Thanks for all your comments. That really helped me alot :)

Answer (score 4):

Your do while loop will execute `Rigidbody2d.velocity = new Vector2(1f, 0f);` every single time around. There's nothing in that loop that's changing. If you did:

```
while (x < y)
{
    a = 5;
    x++;
}
```

There wouldn't be any point in doing that. Simply `a = 5` would have the same effect, just a lot less uneeded looping.

On top of that, you're not changing the value of `x` at all. That's what's causing the issue. You're basically doing

```
while (x < y)
    a = 5;
```

If `x` was less than `y` at the start, `x` will always be less than `y`, so it will keep executing the body of the `while` loop forever, and thus Unity is stuck in the `Update` method.

This has *nothing* to do with the fact that `Update` is called once per frame. This is just a simple infinite loop caused by using a condition that isn't changing. This would block the program even if it was in a different function.

Here's something you can do instead:

```
// Using a property will always return the targets X value when called without having to 
// set it to a variable
private float X 
{ 
    // Called when getting value of X
    get { return Rigidbody2d.transform.position.X; } }  

    // Called when setting the value of X
    set { transform.position = new Vector2(value, transform.position.y); }  
}
private bool isMoving = false;

private void Update () 
{  

    if (X < -4 && !isMoving)
    { 
        Rigidbody2d.velocity = new Vector2(1f, 0f); // Move plank till it reaches point B
        isMoving = true;
    }
    else if (isMoving) 
    { 
        Rigidbody2d.velocity = new Vector(0f, 0f);  // You probably want to reset the 
                                                    // velocity back to 0
        isMoving = false;
    }                                               
}
```

Comment: You should look into properties, because they do what you want but basically for you. In this example, everytime you go to use `X` it's going to get the value directly from the transform, meaning it will always be updated no matter where you use it, and you don't have to keep redeclaring it in different functions. It's captialized to show that it's a property. Also, it's impliciltly `readonly` so I'd get an error if I'd try to change the value, which is what we'd want because changing the value of `x` won't change the real `x` of the `gameObject`.

Comment: @Esla You are blocking the game loop with your while loop. The game calls each script's `Update()` method in turn, draws, and then repeats. If you have a while loop, your Update() method can't complete, and other Update() methods can't be run. You effectively pause the game loop. Furthermore, even if `.position` is a _reference type_ and you're updating it from another thread, you're assigning the x value, a _value type_ to a local variable, which will never be updated unless you update it in the same method.

Comment: private float X => Rigidbody2d.transform.position.X; doesnt work for me , visual studio is throwing me syntax error.  And assigning X value out of update method wouldnt make X to change value

Comment: Right, I forgot, Unity doesn't use C# 7 by default. It's possible to do though, that's what I'm using. I updated my answer to show how to use properties in C# 4. And you're right, it wouldn't, but changing `x` wouldn't change it either. When you store the value of an `int` you're really only storing a copy, so if you change it, your only changing a copy, not the original. I also added the setter so when you set the value of `X` you're changing the value of the position

Comment: @AustinWBryan Thanks that helped me alot... But using if else statement inside update method is kinda bulky as well.. My game takes 2 second before it start. Is there better method of doing same operation without having to load update method with stuff?

Comment: @AustinWBryan its also effecting FPS of game.. i am having 30 FPS with this. Before applying if else statement inside update method i was getting 60+ Fps

Comment: If you don't want thte if statement, you could use the `?:` ternary operator or just extract the method. With this, we're setting the velocity every single frame, when we really only need to set it once if `X < -4` and once more if it is otherwise. I've updated my answer to do that.

Answer (score 2):

As the comment above your Update-method suggests, Update() is called once per frame.
A while-loop will block the Update() until the condition is fullfilled, but it will never be fulfilled when you are blocking the Update()-method.

Try something like this

```
void Update() 
{
     if(this.transform.position.x < -4) 
          Rigidbody2d.velocity = new Vector2(1f, 0f);
}
```

Imagine the gameloop in unity looks something like this (very over-simplified)

```
while(running) 
{
   // Start of frame
   CallUpdateOnGameObjects();
   ProcessPhysics(); // this is where the rigidbody is moved
   DrawEverything();
   // End of frame
}
```

So when your update method is called, you are starting your while-loop, but the condition for the while loop can never be fullfilled, because the gameloop wont ever be able to reach ProcessPhysics().

For reference see
https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/ExecutionOrder.html

Comment: Why the downvote? 
The core of the problem is clearly the misunderstanding that velocity+= new Vector3(1f, 0.0f) will increment the rigidbodys x value, but simply incrementing the velocity in the update method will not have any effect until the physics is processed.

Sure its also programatically incorrect, but i think the main problem is the misunderstanding of unitys gameloop.

Comment: Changing the velocity of your rigidbody will not affect the position of the object until the physics has been processed for that frame. so, get rid of the while-loop as per my example, it is the cause of the block.

Comment: Fredrik perhaps you should add some information to your answer about the game loop. I think Esla still isn't clear on the problem. P.S. I upvoted since this is clearly the correct solution.

Comment: @Fredrik Widerberg , Thanks for you answer "if" statement work in this condition. But i guess its not very accurate way of doing it as putting more stuff inside update method makes application runs slower. There must be some better way of doing it.

Comment: @Esla How is more stuff being put in the update method?

Comment: @john The plank is moving the way i want it to. But my game is quite slow now. I am getting about 30 FPS now which is really bad for 2D game. I dnt know if using else if statement inside update method is causing this issue or not.